# sending all read lines to string array

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

I have a concept but I'm not sure how to go at it. I would like to parse a website and use regex to find certain parts. Then store these parts into a string. After I would like to do the same, but find differences between before and after.

The plan:

1. parse/regex add lines found to the array `before`.
2. refresh the website/parse/regex add lines found to the array `after`.
3. compare all strings before with all of string after. `println` any new ones.
4. send all after strings to before strings.

Then repeat from 2. forever.

Basically its just checking a website for updated code and telling me what's updated.

Firstly, is this doable?

Here's my code for part 1.

```
String before[] = {};
int i = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        before[i]=line;
        System.out.println(before[i]);  
        i++;    
    }
}
```

It doesn't work and I am not sure why.

Comment: `String before[] = {};` is a zero-length array. Also arrays are static in size, once initialized they can't grow. But you can use a list instead, `List<String> befores = new ArrayList<String>();`. Also please check this page - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/738746, here on SO, the summary is that you should use some HTML parser for that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming you're reading from a file:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("oldLinesFilePath"));
List<String> oldLines = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>();

while (s.hasNext()){
    oldLines.add(s.nextLine());
}

s = new Scanner(new File("newLinesFilePath"));

while (s.hasNext()){
    newLines.add(s.nextLine());
}    
s.close();

for(int i = 0; i < newLines.size(); i++) {
   if(!oldLines.contains(newLines.get(i)) {
       System.out.println(newLines.get(i));
   }
}
```